# Weird single table inheritance bug in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I was working on a Rails application today (Ruby 2.1.3/Rails 4.1) where there is several classes inheriting from a single class Item:

Main class is Item, there is a Page class that inherits from Item and DownloadPage class that inherits from Page class. All objects are stored in a single table and are distinguished by Type column containing object's class name (Page, Article, DownloadPage, etc.)

Here is the UML:

[image: UML]

Here what data looks like in the DB (Item table):

[image: DB]

Back to the issue, when application loads, and I go to page#index, all objects of type "Page" from Item table are listed, everything is fine, but when the application uses the class DownloadPage at least once (example: DownloadPage.first), page#index sends every object of Page type PLUS objects of type DownloadPage, which is not normal.

Here is a demo of the issue, notice how SQL query only selects Page type the first time (step 1) and Page+DownloadPage the second time (step 3):

[image]

So my question is, Am I doing something wrong, architecture might be bad or something else? Or is that a rails/ruby bug

OUTPUT:

```
2.1.3 :001 > Page.first

Page Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."type" IN ('Page')

=> #<Page id: 2, type: "Page",... 

2.1.3 :002 > DownloadPage.first

DownloadPage Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."type" IN ('DownloadPage') AND "items"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

=> #<DownloadPage id: 26, type: "DownloadPage",...

2.1.3 :003 > Page.first

Page Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."type" IN ('Page', 'DownloadPage')

=> #<Page id: 2, type: "Page", title: "sdfPage"...
```

Comment: Your image isn't clear. Can you instead just post the queries in your image here ?

Comment: I updated the OP, responses formatting is weird on SO

Comment: Giant screenshots are not especially helpful. Isn't there a more concise way of representing this?

Comment: I suspect this might have to do with autoloading. DownloadPage class wasn't loaded in the first run of Page.first, and it is in the second. Can you confirm?

Comment: I updated the post with console outputs, first query selects Items of type Page, second command uses the class DownloadPage, third query is exactly the same as the first but returns items of type Page AND DownloadPage for some reason

Comment: Nope, I typed Page.all once it selected only Page type items, typed the same command again (without loading DownloadPage.all), it did the same thing as first command, loaded items only of type Page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Page < Item
end

require_dependency 'download_page'
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8699

Comment: Thanks this solves the weird behaviour, but how can I prevent loading of DownloadPages when I do Page.all for example, I only want Pages not both.

Comment: That is the expected behavior since DownloadPages are also Pages. If you only want Pages that are not DownloadPages you will need to add a where clause to restrict it

Comment: thanks! I added bunch of where type "Page" clauses in my scopes and it worked.